# I am getting this error when trying to do an intent to a bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

Here my code:

```
class Principal : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal2)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
        )
    )

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}}
```

---

### i am getting the error in the last two lines of the code. Here the log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.auditoriamedica/com.example.auditoriamedica.views.Principal}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.nav_view) must not
> be null
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.nav_view) must not be null
> at com.example.auditoriamedica.views.Principal.onCreate(Principal.kt:17)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Do you have R.id.nav_view in your R.layout.activity_principal2?Or do you have old  R.layout.activity_principal in your import?

Comment: nav_view not found in layout activity_principal2

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela  Yeah, i know, but nav_view is there and i dont know  why it cant reach it

Comment: @AlexeyBilousov   Yes, i have it in my activity layout, and when i do findViewById(), i CAN find and get access to ir, but when i run the app it stops working

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem is that my app Theme was NoActionBar.
I don't really know why I must have an action bar if I want to use a bottom navigation view. If someone knows how to hide the action bar in a bottomNavigationView please tell me!

Thanks!